# How to install Dryscrape on Windows Anaconda?

Tags: windows, anaconda, python-3.6

I'm trying to follow the instructions but Anaconda Prompt always fail.  How do I install Dryscrape on Windows Anaconda?
https://anaconda.org/floriangeigl/dryscrape

**Anaconda Prompt (Windows)**

`conda install -c floriangeigl dryscrape`

```
> conda install dryscrape

Solving environment: failed

//___________________________________________

> conda install -c floriangeigl dryscrape

Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - dryscrape

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/floriangeigl/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/floriangeigl/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the Files tab of the page you linked, you'll see the package is only available for linux-64 from that channel. Unfortunately, no one else seems to have uploaded that package to a public channel. Checking the [README](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape#supported-platforms), it seems that Windows is supported only via Cygwin.